# php join and count then group and order by

Tags: php, mysql, join, count, group-by

I have two tables;

**Users**

```
id | username   | club 
-----------------------
1  | James5     | 2 
2  | 007        | 1 
3  | xmen       | 2 
4  | terminator | 2
```

**suggestedusers**

```
 id | username | club 
----------------------
 1  | mark     |  2 
 2  | bon      |  1 
 3  | hero     |  2 
 4  | scorpio  |  2 
 5  | lame     |  5
```

How do I join these tables to get the total of the clubs? e.g an answer like

```
 club   |  clubCount 
 -------------------
  2     |  6
  1     |  2 
  5     |  1
```

I was thinking of the following query;

```
SELECT User.club, COUNT(User.club) + COUNT(suggestedusers.club) AS clubCount FROM User, suggestedusers 
GROUP BY User.club 
ORDER BY clubCount DESC
```

But the above script is not working.

Comment: Use Union, but what if a user joins or is suggested for multiple clubs?

Comment: Thanks Strewberry 5. A user can only belong to one club.  And can change  from one club to another if need be but can not be in two clubs at a time.

Actual clubCount represents total number of  users and suggested users in the club.

Answer (score 0):

Your target result is not clear to me.
You can try with this one

```
 Select club, count(club) as clubcount from(
      select users.id, users.username, users.club from users
       UNION
     select suggestedusers.id, suggestedusers.username, 
        suggestedusers.club from suggested users ) group by club, clubcount Order by
     clubcount desc;
```

Comment: Hi Riyad Thanks for your comment, I tried it but got this error "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Answer (score -1):

Assuming what you want is to get the number of users per club for both tables, this should work for you:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT COALESCE(u.club, su.club) AS club
    , COALESCE(count(u.club), count(su.club)) AS clubcount
FROM    Users u

    INNER JOIN Suggestedusers su ON su.club = u.club

      GROUP BY u.club,su.club
    ORDER BY clubcount DESC
```

Please check the names of tables and columns when using in your code.

Comment: HI Nisal I tried your method, it worked for the grouping but the clubCount is still outrageous and does not match the actual count as it is contained in the database